# Data structure for multiple keys having same value in C++

Tags: c++

I am having multiple keys denoting same value in std::unordered_map. Is there any Data Structure in CPP which I can use in order to save memory? In present case, since I am storing same value again and again for a different key, my memory is increasing a lot. There is one solution to create a tuple of keys and store, but that will impact my runtime while retrieving the data. I saw couple of similar questions on stack overflow but didn't find proper solution to it.

Pseudo code -

```
unordered_map<int,int> m ;
m[0] = 0;
m[1] = 0;
m[2] = 0;

cout<<m[2]<<endl;
```

Comment: @Harry multimap is about sharing keys, not values.

Comment: `std::unordered_map<Key, std::shared_ptr<Value>>`?

Comment: How big is your value? How do you populate map with same values?

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity to store values separately with keys just pointing to those values, instead of actually storing the values.

Comment: @GauravSehgal Since my value is of 16 bytes, I am thinking of creating std::bimap of value and int. and in my unordered_map i will be storing my int value corresponding to the actual value. 
But this is still not optimized I feel since there will be repetition of integer

Comment: @Jarod42 I have added a pseudo code for better understanding. My key and data are of 16 bytes

Comment: As Value type is small, indirection doesn't provide gain. And I don't see memory optimization.

Comment: @KirtiKedia The same value of **a particular key** does not make much sense. It would be the same values for **different keys**. Thus given your poor sentence, I was thinking you were talking about the key itself. 

*By looking at the comments, I was not alone to misinterpret your question.*

Comment: @Jarod42 Using std::shared_ptr for both key and value will help to save memory?

Comment: Using `shared_ptr` could save memory if you really share the data which mean you have to keep track of it which affect both memory and performance. Unless your data is really big (millions of items), then no point to make the code more complex and if your data is really big, then you want to profile performance and memory (possibly using tools) if you are serious about it.

Comment: Not for small objects as you have.